# Plotting all files from a directory in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

How to plot all files in directory in gnuplot? I mean the when I have 15 data files I will get 15 graphs.

```
plot '???' with lines
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with just **too many** caveats (spaces in filenames, files not containing data but reside in the folder, etc.). Use it at your own risk.

```gnuplot
plot for [fn in system("ls")] fn with lines title ''.i
```

The proper way is of course naming your files in an ordered manner and rewrite the `for` in a saner manner, like

```gnuplot
plot for [i=1:15] `mydata`.i.`.dat` using 1:2 with lines title `data set `.i
```

Note that the `for` for `plot` is only available in newer versions of `gnuplot`.

**Edit**: per request in comment and chat, this is the final form used. Again, this is quick and dirty and use it at your own risk.

```gnuplot
j=0
do for [fn in system("ls")] {
    j=j+1; set term png
    set output ''.fn.'.png'
    plot fn with lines linecolor rgb "navy" title ''.i 
}
```

Comment: Thank you and what name should have my files? something.dat? Or something1.dat, something2.dat? The first command give an error: `bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(‘`

Comment: It is not for you to run in `bash`, it is for you to run in `gnuplot`.

Comment: Of course, I am sorry. And is it possible to generate one graph from one data? I get one graph with lots of curves.

Comment: Updated per request.

Comment: Thank you I get the graph from the last data in directory. Is it necessary to set a saving plot? I am not sure my names of files are correct. `''.i` means it should name `someting.1`, `something.2` ...?

Comment: Are you plotting them directly to the screen? What is your terminal? `x11`? `wxt`? `qt`? In my last edit, the files should be named mydata1.dat, mydata2.dat mydata3.dat, but you can adapt that part to your need.

Comment: Yes I am plotting directly to the screen, I don't know how to write a command for saving more graphs. I have linux mint, how can I recognize whether I have x11, wxt or qt?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92954/discussion-between-lukas-altman-and-weijun-zhou).

Answer (score 0):

Weijun Zhou already presented you with a working albeit slightly volatile solution. In case you have a lot of data files so that manually renaming them to follow a formula is not realistic, you can check the file format (.txt, .dat, whatever your data is saved as) to filter out unwanted files.

Example: Plot all .txt files in a folder and save them as .pngs for future analysis.

```
do for [fn in system("ls")] {
    len=strlen(fn)
    form=substr(fn,len-3,len)
    if (form eq ".txt") {
        set term png

        data=sprintf("%s",fn)
        filename=sprintf("%s.png",substr(fn,0,len-4))

        set output filename
        plot data using 1:2 title "Data"
        unset output
    }
}
```

This will go through every file, check whether it's a .txt file, and if it is, it will be plotted and saved as a .png with the same name as the original .txt file. This way you can avoid any problems that may be caused by the program attempting to read improper file formats, as long as you don't have any excess .txt files floating in the same folder.

As a side note, in case someone looking at this thread wants to run this on Windows version of Gnuplot, due to different system commands, you need to make a change on the first row:

```
system("ls") => system("dir /b")
```